# How to tap on UIView to capture while using mobile vision face detector

Tags: ios, swift, vision-api

I am trying to capture still image while tap on UIView.

Project from:
https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision

FaceDetectorDemo → FaceDetector → CameraViewController.m

I converted the Face detector project from Objective-C to Swift, but I need to add an additional feature which user tap on the screen to capture but just couldn't figure it out.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var placeholder: UIView! 
var stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

for face in faces
{
  //somewhere in here called faceDetected() method
}

func faceDetected() -> Void
{
    let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(saveToCamera))      
    placeholder.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
    placeholder.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func saveToCamera(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection) {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer!)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, nil, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem run into the `saveToCamera` while tapping on the `UIView`.

Comment: this is just the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265659/how-capture-picture-while-mobile-vision-api-face-tracking , but in ios

Answer (score 2):

- The `saveToCamera` is not being called because when you have added
  `placeholder.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` instead of
  `placeholder.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)` , not `tap` but `tapped`
- At selector the method mus be: `saveToCamera(_:)`

this is the full code. It works.

```
  func faceDetected() {
        let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.saveToCamera(_:)))
        placeholder.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
        placeholder.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }



    @objc func saveToCamera(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection) {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer!)
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the `self.` in `#selector(self.saveToCamera(_:))`?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, it was actually placeholder.addGestureRecognizer(tapped) instead of placeholder.addGestureRecognizer(tap). I just forgot to change while uploading the question

Comment: thanks enea. but it doesn't seem work to me when I apply it within the loop :/

Comment: you need to debug what happens in the loop. Maybe somethig goes wrong there

Comment: @EneaDume if you have spare time to help, I actually just uploaded my project on Github https://github.com/shyanhua/facedetector .. btw many thanks for your advices

Comment: your podfile is missing